# Getting indices for certain percent of a length of a list

Tags: python

```
def get_strings(letters, max_length):
    for i in range(1, max_length + 1):
        for value in product(letters, repeat=i):
            yield "".join(value)

comb = [i for i in get_strings(ascii_lowercase, 4)]
print "# of possible combinations: %s" % len(comb)

def perc(i, tot):
    p = float(i) /float(tot)
    return p * 100

marker = [x for x in range(100) if x % 10 == 0]
marker.pop(0)

# make it 10:0, 20:0, 30:0, 40:0 and so forth...
mark = dict(zip(marker, [0 for i in range(len(marker))]))
print "BEFORE:"
for i in marker:
    print "%s percent index: %s" % (i, mark[i])

l = len(comb)
for i,v in enumerate(comb):
    p = perc(i, l)
    ip = math.ceil(p)
    if ip in marker:
        mark[ip] = i


print "AFTER:"
for i in marker:
    print "%s percent index: %s" % (i, mark[i])
```

OUTPUT:

```
# of possible combinations: 475254
BEFORE:
10 percent index: 0
20 percent index: 0
30 percent index: 0
40 percent index: 0
50 percent index: 0
60 percent index: 0
70 percent index: 0
80 percent index: 0
90 percent index: 0
AFTER:
10 percent index: 47525
20 percent index: 95050
30 percent index: 142576
40 percent index: 190101
50 percent index: 237627
60 percent index: 285152
70 percent index: 332677
80 percent index: 380203
90 percent index: 427728
```

I was able to do it with the above code but it seems very tedious and lots of unnecessary steps (or rather can be combined or reduced).

Any simplifications?

Comment: what is get_strings? Also why are you using `for i,v in enumerate(comb)`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham added get_strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's tackle this part by part.

Firstly, let's simplify percentage calculation

```
perc = lambda i, t: (i * t) / 100
```

Now let's simplify your `marker` calculation

```
marker = xrange(10, 100, 10)
```

Now let's calculate indices for certain percent of a length of a list:

```
 for i in marker:
     print '%s percent index: %s' % (i, perc(i, len(comb))
```

That's it!

---

You could further simplify the above to concisely three lines:

```
 perc = lambda i, t: (i * t) / 100
 for i in xrange(10, 100, 10):
     print '%s percent index: %s' % (i, perc(i, len(comb))
```

---

If you *really* need to store your marker in a `mark` dict, use a dict comprehension

```
mark = {i: perc(i, len(comb)) for i in xrange(10, 100, 10)}
```

---

This whole part of your code is probably unnecessary:

```
marker = [x for x in range(100) if x % 10 == 0]
marker.pop(0)

# make it 10:0, 20:0, 30:0, 40:0 and so forth...
mark = dict(zip(marker, [0 for i in range(len(marker))]))
print "BEFORE:"
for i in marker:
    print "%s percent index: %s" % (i, mark[i])

l = len(comb)
for i,v in enumerate(comb):
    p = perc(i, l)
    ip = math.ceil(p)
    if ip in marker:
        mark[ip] = i
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `xrange`, some of your list comprehensions are also unnecessary:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def get_strings(letters, max_length):
    return ("".join(value) for i in range(1, max_length + 1)
            for value in product(letters, repeat=i))

comb = [i for i in get_strings(ascii_lowercase, 4)]

print "# of possible combinations: {}".format(len(comb))

# use an OrderedDict to maintain order, create the keys using a start
# of 10 and a step size of ten
mark = OrderedDict.fromkeys(xrange(10, 100, 10),0,)

# iterate over the items to avoid unnecessary lookups
print "BEFORE:"
for k, v in mark.iteritems():
    print "{} percent index: {}".format(k, v)

l = len(comb)
# use keys of dict 
for i in mark:
    mark[i] = int(float(i) * l / 100)

print "AFTER:"
for k,v in mark.iteritems():
    print "{} percent index: {}".format(k, v)
```

There is no need for a function for the percent calculation, `range` should not be used in python2 unless you actually want a list.